# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype' during importing h5py

Tags: python

```
import h5py
  File "/home/rajnish/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py/h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv
  File "h5py/numpy.pxd", line 66, in init h5py.h5t
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: I also see this error, when Keras initially imports h5py:
`
    File "miniconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    import h5py
    File "miniconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
    File "h5py\h5t.pxd", line 14, in init h5py._conv
    File "h5py\numpy.pxd", line 66, in init h5py.h5t
        AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'`